# Vaadin EmbedSWF

Tags: java, javascript, components, vaadin, youtube-javascript-api

I wanted to use the YouTube add-on but it's not compatible with Vaadin 7. So i thought maybe the AbstractJavaScriptComponent could solve all of my problems.

So i thought creating a javascript which embeds swfobject would solve the problem. But this doesn't work. I think the problem is that the ytapiplayer isn't a valid tag...

id (String, required) specifies the id of the HTML element (containing your alternative content) you would like to have replaced by your Flash content. And i thought i solved it by setting the style name.

**youtubeconnector.js**

```
gui_components_YouTuber =
function()
{
    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/DuYVDHfaCyM?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3","ytapiplayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);

    function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
        ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
    }

    function play() {
      if (ytplayer) {
        ytplayer.playVideo();
      }
    }
}
```

**YouTuber.java**

```
package gui.components;

import com.vaadin.annotations.JavaScript;
import com.vaadin.ui.AbstractJavaScriptComponent;

@JavaScript({"swfobject.js", "youtubeconnector.js"})
public class YouTuber extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent
{
    public YouTuber()
    {
        setStyleName("ytapiplayer");
    }
}
```

Main problem is that swfobject.embedSWF wants a DIV element to link to. Is it possible create something like that? I tried Document.get().. but this results in an unsatified link error...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Component.setDebugId(divId) and then link into it in the js side...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the BrowserFrame component from vaadin with the youtube addon?

Personally I use this for multiple things, external pdf's, if i want to embed things. And it also works to link to other websites in a frame or other projects. So i'm thinking the following should work for you too.

```
BrowserFrame external = new BrowserFrame(null, new ExternalResource("http:///link"));
Layout.add(external);
```

Well honestly might be off with what addon you mean, to use the external resource make sure it is hosted and accessible.